# Some P/Invoke C# to C marshalling questions working with booleans in structs

Tags: c#, c, struct, pinvoke, boolean

I have some problems working with boolean types and marshalling this in a struct back and forth between C# and C. I am very rusty in C but hopefully there's nothing crucially wrong in that part.

As far as I've read/seen, .NET Boolean and **C# bool type is 4 bytes** long whilst the **C type bool is only 1 byte**. For memory footprint reasons, **I do not which to use the defined BOOL 4 bytes version in the C code**.

Here is some simple test code that hopefully will make my questions clear:

---

C code:

```
typedef struct
{
        double SomeDouble1;
        double SomeDouble2;
        int SomeInteger;
        bool SomeBool1;
        bool SomeBool2;
} TestStruct;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) TestStruct* __stdcall TestGetBackStruct(TestStruct* structs);

__declspec(dllexport) TestStruct* __stdcall TestGetBackStruct(TestStruct* structs)
{
    return structs;
}
```

---

I call this code in C# using the following definitions:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct TestStruct
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public double SomeDouble1;
        [FieldOffset(8)]
        public double SomeDouble2;

        [FieldOffset(16)]
        public int SomeInteger;

        [FieldOffset(17), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
        public bool SomeBool1;
        [FieldOffset(18), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
        public bool SomeBool2;
    };

    [DllImport("Front.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern IntPtr TestGetBackStruct([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 1)] TestStruct[] structs);
```

and here is the actual test function in C#:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test_CheckStructParsing()
    {
        var theStruct = new TestStruct();
        theStruct.SomeDouble1 = 1.1;
        theStruct.SomeDouble2 = 1.2;
        theStruct.SomeInteger = 1;
        theStruct.SomeBool1 = true;
        theStruct.SomeBool2 = false;

        var structs = new TestStruct[] { theStruct };

        IntPtr ptr = TestGetBackStruct(structs);

        var resultStruct = (TestStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(TestStruct));
    }
```

This works in the sense that **I do get a struct back** (using the debugger to inspect it), **but with totally wrong values**. I.e. the marshalling does not work at all. I've tried different version of the C# struct without success. So here are my questions (1 & 2 most important):

1. **Is the C function correct for this purpose?**
2. **How is the struct to be written correctly in order to get me the correct values in the struct back to C#?** (Is it even necessary to define the struct with the StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit) attribute using the FieldOffset values or can I use StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential) instead)?
3. Since I am returning a pointer to the TestStruct in C, I guess it should be possible to get back an **array of TestStructs in C#**. But this does not seem to be possible using the  Marshal.PtrToStructure function. Would it be possible in some other way?
4. Apparantly it is possible to use something called **unions in C** by having multiple struct fields point to the same memory allocation using the same FieldOffset attribute value. I understand this, but I still **don't get yet when such scenario would be useful**. Please enlighten me.
5. Can someone **recommend a good book on C# P/Invoke  to C/C++?** *I am getting a bit tired of getting pieces of information here and there on the web.*

**Much obliged for help with these questions. I hope they were not too many.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stop using `LayoutKind.Explicit` and get rid of the `FieldOffset` attributes and your code will work.  Your offsets were not correctly aligning the fields.

```
public struct TestStruct
{
    public double SomeDouble1;
    public double SomeDouble2;
    public int SomeInteger;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public bool SomeBool1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public bool SomeBool2;
};
```

Declare the function in C# like this:

```
public static extern void TestGetBackStruct(TestStruct[] structs);
```

The default marshalling will match your C++ declaration (your code is C++ rather than C in fact) but you must make sure that your allocate the `TestStruct[]` parameter in the C# code before calling the function.  Normally you would also pass the length of the array as a parameter so that the C++ code knows how many structs there are.

Please don't try to return the array of structures from the function. Use the `structs` parameter as an in/out parameter.

I know of no book with an emphasis on P/Invoke. It appears to be something of a black art!

Comment: The argument isn't really an array.  It should be declared as `out TestStruct retval`

Comment: Thanks for the info! However I do think I am allocating the TestStruct[] parameter: var structs = new TestStruct[] { theStruct }; before calling the function. Also, I noticed that all parameters, expect the integer one are actually correctly given back when adding a Console.WriteLine at the end on all struct fields on resultStruct. But the debugger still gives values that are totally off. What's up with that? :( And, quriosity killed the cat: what makes my code more c++ like than C like?

Comment: `extern "C"` is a tell-tale sign. Do you actually need an array of structs or, as @Hans says, are you just after a single item?

Comment: Ah, now I see where the fieldoffset was wrong. The boolean fields should have had fieldoffset 20 and 21 instead since an integer is 4 bytes. But your code works like a charm though and is better. Though questions #3, #4, #5 and "why debugger gives wrong values" are still open though.

Comment: #3: I think I covered that. Allocate the array in the C# code and let the C++ code populate it. Don't try to allocate the memory in C++ and deallocate it in C#. That won't work. #4: Don't bother with unions. They'll just cause you grief. They make life hard for the marshaller. P/Invoke is hard enough already. #5: I don't know of any such book.

Comment: Ok, I understand the C++/C diff then. Well, my need is really to get the marshalling correct so that I can trust the values to be correct in C. The example in this code was just trying to aim for this really in order to validate the struct values correctness as used in C. Though I think Hans is pointing out a better way to get a an Struc array back from C and I think that is a good answer to #3 of how to be able to get back and array of structs using an out parameter instead of a return value. Black arts, indeed... (Indeed for my example I probably did have to use an array.)

Comment: "Don't try to allocate the memory in C++ and deallocate it in C#". Agred. But as you can see from my previous comment, it was never my intention here to have the C++ code populate the struct. Passing the same values back is just to enable verification of values in C# as used in C. There are probably better ways to do this that I did not think of... :(